# Hadoop put: unexpected URISyntaxException

Tags: hadoop

I get Hadoop unexpected URISyntaxException when I use Hadoop put command to upload a zip file on the hdfs. What I want to do is extract the contents of a file into a directory on hdfs. I am new to Hadoop and super confused. This is the command I use:

```
hadoop fs -put D:\\Big%20Data\\cookbook_text.zip /user/anmol/anmol-hw-1
```

Comment: Please could you share the full error?

Comment: The complete error is, put: unexpected URISyntaxException. That is it. That's what it shows.